# Unable to boot to Windows 8

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows-8, system-installation

I have a laptop that came with Windows 8 preinstalled, on which I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. It was successfully installed and when I restart it and select Ubuntu it boots to Ubuntu and works OK, but when I restart it and try to select Windows 8 it gives me this error message:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next." 
 3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator it computer manufacturer for assistance.  

 File: \Boot\BCD
 Status: 0xc000000c
 Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the MBR with the Windows 8 cd, but this will usurp grub and Ubuntu.

It is possible that windows has the boot information in another drive.

Try booting from the windows 8 cd, and finding where the BCD file is supposed to be.
from the repair console:
    `bcdedit /enum all`

This will show all of the boot information that windows needs. If this is on a different partition then grub is pointing it to, it will give this error.